# Disk usage - du showing different results

Tags: linux, du, disk-access

I am confused with `du` command because it gives different result for files.

```
[root@gerrh6-05 sathish]# du -s saravana/admin/sqlnet.ora
4       saravana/admin/sqlnet.ora
[root@gerrh6-05 sathish]# du -h saravana/admin/sqlnet.ora
4.0K    saravana/admin/sqlnet.ora
[root@gerrh6-05 sathish]# du -b saravana/admin/sqlnet.ora
65      saravana/admin/sqlnet.ora
[root@gerrh6-05 sathish]# du -bh saravana/admin/sqlnet.ora
65      saravana/admin/sqlnet.ora


[root@gerrh6-05 sathish]# ll -h saravana/admin/sqlnet.ora
-rw-r----- 1 root root 65 May 18 03:47 saravana/admin/sqlnet.ora
```

Disk usage summary return invalid result(`-s` gives **4** and `-b` gives **65**), where bytes(**-b**) return same as `ll` result.

```
[root@gerrh6-05 sathish]# du -sh saravana/admin
114M    saravana/admin

[root@gerrh6-05 sathish]# du -bh saravana/admin
12K     saravana/admin/1/xdb_wallet
7.4K    saravana/admin/1/pfile
7.2M    saravana/admin/1/test/result/data
7.6M    saravana/admin/1/test/result
7.0M    saravana/admin/1/test/data
28M     saravana/admin/1/test
7.2M    saravana/admin/1/adump
4.0K    saravana/admin/1/logbook/controlfile_trace
8.0K    saravana/admin/1/logbook
4.2K    saravana/admin/1/dpdump
35M     saravana/admin/1
35M     saravana/admin
```

From above which is correct size of `/admin dir` **35M** or **114M**.

Which one I should take?

Note: I am working on a linux machine where I don't have UI.Purpose why I ma looking for this is, I writing a script to taking backup. I should split folders and files based on size limit 4GB. Which one I should take to count.Because the different is large!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man du`:

> `--apparent-size`: print apparent sizes, rather than disk usage; although the apparent size is usually smaller, it may be larger due to holes in ('sparse') files, internal fragmentation, indirect blocks, and the like
>
> `-b, --bytes`: equivalent to `--apparent-size --block-size=1`

So, `-b` tells you how much data is stored; without it, you get how much disk space is used. Both are "correct size", for different definition of "size".